# Unable to access properties of Firebase object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jjNx.png)

```
$('#btn_searchUser').click(function(){
  var emailSearch = $('#txt_searchEmail').val();
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');

  rootRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailSearch).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    displayUserDetails(snapshot);
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});

function displayUserDetails(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Logging the `data` shows the object as expected, but `data.name` or any other method I've tried logs `undefined`! I'm very new to JS so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I know its to do with not having access to the key... but .key simply returns the parent, users.

Comment: Could you show us what the `data` object looks like when you log it to the console

Comment: yes i added the image to the post. Thanks

Comment: From the output it looks like you have an object within an object, therefore you need to use this to get the `name` property value: `data['-KdgYqdfVX3hlOxDisNk'].name`

Comment: thats worked thank you mate. Just need to figure out how to get that value now then :)

Comment: If you want to loop through them all you can use `Object.keys()`, but to get a specific user you'd need to know their Id beforehand

Comment: okay ill have a go at it, thank you very much mate.